# popen with AWK and pipes - python

Tags: python, pipe, popen

I'm using Python 2.6 and must use `popen` for this command

```
dmidecode | grep -i cpu | awk '{print $5}' | head -n1
```

i tried many combination like:

```
tmp = os.popen(['dmidecode ', 'grep -i cpu ' 'awk '{print $5}'' 'head -n1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But none of them is working and every time I tried to play with it I get different errors, sometime syntax sometime "no keyword arguments"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please wrap your code in code tags and be clear in your question as it is not clear as of now.

Comment: Did you know there's a [module to use dmidecode](https://github.com/nima/python-dmidecode)?